# Auto-collapse subitems when using drag and drop for large hierarchical lists?

Tags: hierarchy, drag-n-drop

We're looking at a reusable interface that can allow user to view tabular data with hierarchical structure and reorganize/re-order items.

Some use cases for this:

- Updating priority of work on a schedule. Work may be grouped together in subunits. As a project manager, I want the ability to re-prioritize subunits of work so my team picks up the highest priority items off the top of the list.
- Re-ordering items to present info to the stakeholders in a logical fashion. As a account manager, when I have financial update meetings with project stakeholders, I want the ability to reorganize the work list based on its importance to a specific stakeholder so I can more easily provide them with project updates.

Here's one sample view of one list (tabular view of a project schedule)

[image]

Note: this is just one view, the hierarchical structure to the left is fairly consistent across different use cases, but the data on the right varies. I don't think it matters for our problem.

Because this is a web app, there's a certain expectation from the users that they ought to be able to reorder items using drag and drop interactions. However, drag and drop doesn't work very well for large lists because you need to deal with the page scrolling AND the drag and drop action.

Because of the way our hierarchical lists are set up (items can only be moved within their respective groups), we have the option of collapsing the group to reduce the annoyance caused by page scrolling, but should we be doing so?

To state this clearly:

**Should the system automatically collapse the groups to hide subitems as soon as the user starts dragging on the group header to facilitate reordering?**

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOXdiO.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

I'm a bit concern with the possibility of page jumping if the user is dragging on a group in the middle of the list and several large groups at the top suddenly collapses on them.

Note: I'm not tied to drag and drop behaviour at all. This is just something the users are familiar with. So feel free to suggest alternate ways of visually re-ordering potentially large lists.

Comment: What's this menu for? Is it just a regular navigational menu?

Comment: This is not a menu. This is a hierarchical list. You can picture it as the "Outline" mode of a large MS Word document. The user would like to reorder the sections.

Comment: Isn't a hierarchical list navigation? Can you give us a little bit more insight on what this list does, or what this list is for?

Comment: What you’ve described is an interface, not a user experience problem. We don’t know who your users are or what they’re trying to do, so a good answer is impossible.

Comment: An interface problem ***is*** a UX problem

Comment: This is an interaction that we're attempting to reuse in various modules within the system. This is the reason why I'm refraining from giving a single specific scenario. I'll update the question with some use cases... hang tight.

Comment: Thanks @nightning - it's always a good idea to give some background, if you have it, so us designers who are outside looking in, could potentially give some input!

Comment: @Majo0od, an interface problem alone is not a UX problem—without a user, there is no user experience.

Comment: @DanielDeLaney that's weird, what do you think an interface is for? The computer isn't going to use it, a person will!

Comment: Great point @Majo0od, you’ve perfectly explained my position. An interface isn’t complete without a user, so you can’t study it in isolation.

Comment: @DanielDeLaney I'm legitimately confused. You can still talk about the UX of an interface and how it works.

Comment: the user wil drag and drop JUST for reordering?

Comment: For now, yes, just assume drag and drop is only use for reordering. They will not use drag and drop to add to or remove from the list.

Comment: every type of item should be draggable to reorder? (e.g. 216,217,218 are all in a different hierarchy, every one is switcheable with items of their own hierarchy? or just 216, the one with the highest hierarchy?)

Comment: The sample schedule is from an old schedule and actually isn't very representative. Assume you have 3 levels, yellow, blue and white. Items within each color can be reordered (bringing its subitems along for the ride). But you cannot move a yellow item down into a blue or white level. http://i.stack.imgur.com/WTjMJ.png

Comment: @Majo0od, interfaces don’t have experiences, much less *user* experiences—they are inanimate. You need a user in order to have a user experience. Users are the reason we make interfaces, and their experiences are the way we measure whether our interfaces are successfully designed.

Comment: @DanielDeLaney Ummm to get back to the question. The user (could be a project manager, or an account executive) needs controls on a web interface to reorder groups of items on a list (e.g. a schedule). Now that you have the context, do you have any suggestions on how to best allow them to do so if the list can be up to 200 items long?

Comment: I love the post-it note with red tape attached to it ... really caught my attention and made me read what was on it. Wondering if/where I could apply that technique anywhere in my own designs...

Comment: @HC_ Oh that's a standard "comment" element provided by Balsamiq. I typically use something like that for annotation on wireframes. It makes it very obvious it's not a part of the UI and should be read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The drag-and-drop method certainly has negative aspects, particularly when the list is long enough to overflow the page, but it may still be your best option.

I don’t think it’s beneficial to collapse groups automatically when the user starts dragging a row. That would interrupt the user’s action by moving everything around while he’s trying to interact with it, creating a moving target. To mitigate that problem somewhat, you could require that the user enter a reorder mode (similar to what you might be familiar with in iOS) in which groups are collapsed:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Fqz2.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

There are a few alternate patterns that come to mind. None are great, but they’re options. First, if the list has the potential to become *very* long, so that drag-and-drop is obviously unfeasible, there’s the GoodReads method, also used by Netflix:

[image: Manual list position entry]

The user can [manually enter the numeric position](http://gfycat.com/SevereAstonishingAmericanredsquirrel) to update the list order. Instead of natural drag input, which even small children can master, the user has to remember numbers and type them in. This is especially painful on mobile operating systems, where the keyboard often covers much of the screen, and users hate typing.

Another option is to offer up and down arrows that the user can click/tap to move a row one position up or down, a “stepper” control:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f3ZIf2.png)</sup>

This makes it tedious to move a row many positions up or down. You could try combining drag-and-drop, direct input, and stepper so that the user can choose which method is appropriate:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIfIG5.png)</sup>

Again, none of these are perfect, I’m just submitting options to help you think through the problem. Maybe user testing can be your guide from here.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the reorder mode option and your list of alternatives for ordering. I'm familiar with these and agree with pretty much all your comments that nothing is ideal. Your "mode" suggestion strangely reminds me perhaps the system can auto-detect the list size and represent alternate controls (e.g. stepper + input) on these more edge case large schedules. Food for thought.

Comment: This answer sums it up. If you're in a dilemma between drag and drop or click/edit to change order, just think about laptop users. Dragging with the trackpad is quite inefficient. This should help you narrow down your options.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Asana example]If you have a menu in the left rail for the top categories, perhaps then you could use drag and drop for sorting by the category names. Similarly to Asana.

Comment: This is a nice alternate approach to allow drag and drop on 2 levels. It separates the drag to order to within a group or reorder groups themselves in 2 separate area. It doesn't quite work in my scenario though to have an extra left menu because of the complexity of the data.

+1 though because this is a variable general solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am basically agree with Daniel, auto collapsing groups doesn't work well. I would still vote for drag&drop option if 
1. User has relatively small lists upto 20-30 position in most cases or rearranges them rarely in case of bigger list
2. User needs precise control for item location: say, to move item #5 between #23 and #24 so item #23 becomes #22 and item #5 becomes #23. That is critical for example to linear stories/presentations or project management/planning where particular items are interconnected.
3. This basically means user knows all his items very well at a given point of time to make such decisions.

In many cases user needs relative items rearrangement/sorting to separate for example more important items from less important. The UI patterns for such priority escalation and de escalation are usually more user friendly (simple button/dropdown) so I would advise to consider them as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't auto-collapse because it's unexpected. It could cause a drastic change in the appearance of the list upon drag initiation. Plus it raises the question of *"do you automatically uncollapse after the drop or cancel?"*

I'd also avoid a special reordering mode - I think that would cause more confusion than it's worth.

Drag/drop + scrolling is always tricky (both the implementation and UX are tricky). Some things to make it more usable are:

1) Good feedback - clearly indicate what is being dragged and the current (potential) drop location.

2) Proper scrolling speed.

3) Easy cancellation - escape key or dropping outside the list cancels the operation. When dragging outside the list there should be feedback that a drop here will cancel the operation, mouse pointer could change to indicate "cancel" (cursor: no-drop).

4) Provide an undo operation.

In addition to reordering by drag/drop you could allow reorder via cut/paste. I would have 2 paste actions: "Paste before" and "Paste after". Although this is somewhat unconventional you need the 2 actions in order to be able to both paste before the first item in the list and paste after the last item. And it never hurts to be explicit.